# Extract the fields in json log if the filed exists using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract the fields in the below sample data

```
{"Value":{"Data":{"Items":[{"FieldType":"ABC","Value":"*****"},{"FieldType":"ACB","Value":"*****"},{"FieldType":"ABCD","Value":"*****"},,{"FieldType":"XYZ","Value":"*****"}],"EncryptedDocKey":"*****","Domain":"*****","Partner":"***","Carrier":"****"},"RequestTrackerId":"****","Message":"OK"},"Formatters":[],"ContentTypes":[],"DeclaredType":null,"StatusCode":null}

{"Value":{"Data":{"Items":[{"FieldType":"ABC","Value":"*****"},{"FieldType":"XYZ","Value":"*****"},{"FieldType":"ACD","Value":"*****"}],,"EncryptedDocKey":"*****","Domain":"*****","Partner":"***","Carrier":"****"},"RequestTrackerId":"****","Message":"OK"},"Formatters":[],"ContentTypes":[],"DeclaredType":null,"StatusCode":null}

{"Value":{"Data":{"Items":[{"FieldType":"XYZ","Value":"*****"},{"FieldType":"ACD","Value":"*****"}],,"EncryptedDocKey":"*****","Domain":"*****","Partner":"***","Carrier":"****"},"RequestTrackerId":"****","Message":"OK"},"Formatters":[],"ContentTypes":[],"DeclaredType":null,"StatusCode":null}

{"Value":{"Data":{"Items":[{"FieldType":"ABCD","Value":"*****"}],,"EncryptedDocKey":"*****","Domain":"*****","Partner":"***","Carrier":"****"},"RequestTrackerId":"****","Message":"OK"},"Formatters":[],"ContentTypes":[],"DeclaredType":null,"StatusCode":null}
```

I need to extract the text next to `FieldType (ABC,XYZ,ABCD,ACB,ACB ...)` into V1,V2,V3,V4,V5 etc...

I have a regex that can get if there are three fields but the regex is not mapping if there are more or less than 3 fields.

I tried this regex

```
.?"FieldType":"(?<V1>\w+)".+?"FieldType":"(?<V2>\w+).+?"FieldType":"(?<V3>\w+)
```

Also I want to extract all the fields in fieldtype and ,EncryptedDocKey,Domain,Partner,Carrier,RequestTrackerId,Message,Formatters,ContentTypes,DeclaredType,StatusCode

Comment: Why you don't use JSON.NET?

Comment: I strongly suggest you do not parse JSON yourself, and certainly not with regexes. Here's an article I wrote on the topic: https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/7-things-never-code/

Answer (score 0):

It'd be unnecessary to apply regular expressions here, yet if you have to, an expression similar to:

```
"(FieldType)":"([^"]+)"|"(message)":"([^"]+)"
```

might extract those desired key values.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/L9aVBS/1/)